# Python3 subprocess in multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, python-multiprocessing

I'm a beginner in writing concurrent code.

I'm writing a code that takes the users ID and tries to return a full name of the user, the query takes a second or so to execute, so I was hoping to involve multiprocessing to collect the data faster; I think I'm close, but I don't get how the framework needs to be implemented correctly.

```
from subprocess import getoutput
from multiprocessing import Pool

all_users = ['User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4', 'User5', 'User6'] # example list

def get_name(userid):
    name = getoutput('net users {} /domain | findstr "full name:"'.format(userid)).replace('Full Name', '').strip().split('\n')[0]
    return {userid : name}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as p:
        print(p.map(get_name, all_users))

    print(' --------- finished')

print(' - exiting - '))
```

This is just a single step in a multi-step script; and the output appears as follows: (ignore the "the user name could not be found" part, just an example)

```
 - exiting -
 - exiting -
 - exiting -
 - exiting -
[{'User1': 'The user name could not be found.'}, {'User2': 'The user name could not be found.'}, {'User3': 'The user name could not be found.'}, {'User4': 'The user name could not be found.'}, {'User5': 'The user name could not be found.'}, {'User6': 'The user name could not be found.'}]
 --------- finished
 - exiting -
```

I'm trying to structure the program as follows:

1. Get list of users
2. Convert ID to names (asap, by spawning a separate process for each function call)
3. Wait for the 2nd step to complete fully and then work with the data that was returned;

I've tried reading on the subject from various sources, but I just can't grasp the structure somehow... as I understood, I'm getting four - exiting - statements at the beginning as I have 4 cores, but how do I encapsulate this part of the code so that while it's running, nothing else is happening and the - exiting - is written only once at the end of it.

Comment: Found an interesting explanation;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626474/9039988

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pool.close() statement in your with loop:

```
with Pool(4) as p:
    print(p.map(get_name, all_users))
    p.close()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "with" statement handle the closing of the Pool object automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Josh Hayes already gave the right answer. If you use pool like that, it is going to call `terminate` on exit (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process) since Python 3.3. You have to add `p.close()` to properly finish. However, your last bracket is too much and you should not see more than one `finished` and `exiting` print because those calls are not within the pool. How do you start your script? Which Python version are you using?

Edit:
You may try to add:

```
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

all_users = ['User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4', 'User5', 'User6'] # example list

def get_name(userid):
    name = getoutput('net users {} /domain | findstr "full name:"'.format(userid)).replace('Full Name', '').strip().split('\n')[0]
    print(info("p "))
    return {userid : name}
```

and call `info("whatever")` instead of `exiting` and see which processes are at work here.
Which OS are you using? At least on Linux it makes sense.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.3 x64;

That really is the whole script that I've pasted and the output is bizarre... 4 exit statements at the beginning and then the script runs and then the rest of things happen in order;

P.S. Does "with" statement not handle the automatic closure of Pool objects?

Comment: I am a bit confused. I tested it using Python 3.5.2 and my processes are not terminated and the main process is waiting for all to finish. However, in the documentation it states
`terminate()
Stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work. When the pool object is garbage collected terminate() will be called immediately.`
New in version 3.3: Pool objects now support the context management protocol – see Context Manager Types. __enter__() returns the pool object, and __exit__() calls terminate().

Answer (score 0):

Similar question was answered in the following link:
[multiple output returned from python multiprocessing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583025/multiple-output-returned-from-python-multiprocessing-function)

To summarize:

```
# Import stuff
#If the worker code is in the main thread, exclude it from the if statement:
def worker():
    #worker code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #execute whatever you want, it will only be executed 
    #as often as you intend it to
    #execute the function that starts multiprocessing, 

#All code outside of the if statement will be executed multiple times
#depending on the # of assigned worker threads.
```